# How select a ListBox when app loads?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, listbox

I have a ListBox which show several images, every image has two status SELECTED and UNSELECTED.
Switching from one status to another makes the image change url - the IDEA is like a Radio Buttons

No action when a user click on a SELECTED image.
When a user click another UNSELECTED that image will be SELECTED and the previosly one will go in UNSELECTED.

Now in my code in Floors_SelectionChanged I am able to handle this scenario, my problem is when the application start I need PRE-SELECT and image.

I would need to know:

- If this approach with ListBox is appropirate component for this
  scenario, any better alterantives?
- How to make this PRE-SELECTION happen?

  ```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="FloorsListboxDataTemplate">
      <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     Text="{Binding Description,
                     FallbackValue='Description'}">
          </TextBlock>
          <Image x:Name="FloorImage"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Source="{Binding ImageUrlCurrent}"/>
      </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>


          <Custom:SurfaceListBox x:Name="FloorsSurfaceListBox"
                         SelectionChanged="Floors_SelectionChanged"
                         Loaded="FloorsSurfaceListBox_Loaded"
                         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource FloorsListboxDataTemplate}">
  ```

Comment: What's meen `PRE-SELECT`? May be try this: `<Custom:SurfaceListBox SelectedIndex="0" ... />` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The proper approach for most WPF applications is MVVM design
2. Can you set `SelectedIndex = 0` when your ListBox's `Loaded` event is fired?  IF you're using x:Name on ListBox, can you call listbx.SelectedIndex = 0 when your custom control's `Loaded` event is fired?